# c# passing variables to class

Tags: c#, using, opentk, game-loop

here is example of my game class (opens opentk graphics window)

```
   class Game : GameWindow
    {
        public Game()  : base(320, 240, OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode.Default, "OpenTK Quick Start Sample")
        {
            VSync = VSyncMode.On;
        }    
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {  
            base.OnLoad(e); 
            GL.ClearColor(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        }
        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        { 
            int i =1;
            //does stuff 
        }
```

The game class is started like this:

```
    public partial class tk1 : Form
    { 
        public tk1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tk1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Game game;
            this.Show();
            game = new Game(); 
            game.Run(30.0);
        }
```

In original example game instance is wrapped in "using" statement, but i see no difference with out it, one thing i cant do is make game global,
why would i want to? cause i cant figure out how to update "i" in game instance with tk1.numbericUpDown1.value....
explanation?

Comment: Do you know what `using` means in your context?

Comment: setting i at class level as public instance member in Game class?

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `i` field public or make it a public property, so you can access it from outside.

```
class Game : GameWindow
    {
        public int i;

    public Game()  : base(320, 240, OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode.Default, "OpenTK Quick Start Sample")
    {
        VSync = VSyncMode.On;
    }    
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {  
        base.OnLoad(e); 
        GL.ClearColor(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
    }
    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    { 
        i =1;
        //does stuff 
    }
}
```

Then you can access this field from tk1 class.

```
public partial class tk1 : Form
    { 
        Game game;
        public tk1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tk1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            game = new Game(); 
            game.Run(30.0);
            game.i = 10; 
        }

        private void numbericUpDown1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
              game.i = tk1.numbericUpDown1;
        }
```

Comment: thanks , but although it passes, it only does once during load, doesnt update upon change of number box (even after changing 10 to numericupdown.value)

Comment: @doggy It's just a clue how you can work with I. You can do with i whatever you want. I updated answer with example that updates i after every click on numbericUpDown1.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The `using` statement is used so that the `Game` object properly gets disposed after it is used (when the using statement ends).

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called.

It would be recommend to Dispose your Game object correctly, or else there is a good chance you can get a memory leak. If you update your code so that the Game variable is class scope (and not method), you can dispose it in the class's finalizer.

```
~tk1()
{
   _game.Dispose();
}
```

More [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

**2.** To accomplish what you need, you do not want to create a local instance of your Game object, because whenever the method is finished executing it will no longer be available for you to use elsewhere. Instead, move your Game object to the class level.

```
  public partial class tk1 : Form
    { 
       private Game _game;

        public tk1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tk1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            if (_game == null) _game = new Game(); 
            _game.Run(30.0);
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 !  I tried this example works great! (mine failed when i made game public)  also thanks for explanation of dispose, this will clean up a problem i have been noticing working with other class files, i will put using back,  but isnt c# suppose to dispose automatically?

Comment: @doggy you are right. C# does have built-in garbage collection, but a lot of it has to do with different conditions that are based on when the framework decided to "collect". See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx . Also, if this helped you out, and you feel that your question is answered, please do not forget to accept the answer by pressing the checkmark :)

Comment: Thanks again guys! my check marks will show for both of you after i get better rep!... only need 2 more points!